# SetSpatialFilter worked unexpected when using OGR by Python

Tags: geometry, ogr, filter

I am using OGR Python binding to read the shapefile, this is the code:

```
.....
bbox="POLYGON ((20.18164062 30.63867188,20.63867188 30.63867188,20.63867188 30.18164062,20.18164062 30.18164062,20.18164062 30.63867188))";
print "fs:before:",datalayer.GetFeatureCount()
datalayer.SetSpatialFilter(bbox)
print "fs:after :",datalayer.GetFeatureCount()
for feature in datalayer:
    geometry = feature.geometry().Clone()
    if not geometry.Intersect(bbox):
        continue    
    # do my job
```

However the above codes will give me output like:

```
fs:before: 156396
ERROR 1: Attempt to read shape with feature id (157823) out of available range.
..................................
ERROR 1: Attempt to read shape with feature id (160730) out of available range.
More than 1000 errors or warnings have been reported. No more will be reported from now.
fs:after : 0
```

It seems that OGR try to read a feature no exist in the shapefile. Since there are no features with the id in the output. Neither for id "157823" or "160730".

And if I comment line:

```
datalayer.SetSpatialFilter(bbox)
```

No errors occur.

And this is a screenshot of the data and the bbox used as filter:

http://pbrd.co/1kAn4R3

The green features are my data, and the red square is the bbox used to filter the features.

What's the problem?

---

Update the complete codes:

```
def renderTile(coord,items):
    bbox=create_bbox(coord,0.15)

    for item in items:
        datalayer,datasource=_open_layers(item)
        _get_features(coord,bbox,datalayer])


def _open_layers(path):
    datasource=ogr.Open(path)
    datalayer = datasource.GetLayer(0)
    return datalayer,datasource

def _get_features(coord,bbox,datalayer):
    #print "fs:before :",datalayer.GetFeatureCount()
    datalayer.SetAttributeFilter('{0} <= {1}'.format('FSCALE',coord.zoom+1))
    datalayer.SetSpatialFilter(bbox)
    #print "fs:after :",datalayer.GetFeatureCount()

    for feature in datalayer:
        #print feature.GetFID()
        geometry = feature.geometry().Clone()
        if not geometry.Intersect(bbox):
            continue        

        geometry = geometry.Intersection(bbox)
        handle_result(feature,geometry)


coord =(10,12000,2000)
items= ["/home/kk/data/shps/points.shp","/home/kk/data/shps/roads.shp"......];
renderTile(coord,items)
```

The above codes are served by werkzeug. The `coord` is create by HTTP parameters, the `items` are read from configuration file.

Comment: Do you get correct subset without errors by using ogrinfo or ogr2ogr by using -spat and your BBOX? Do you know that your shapefile is valid and that the possible .qix or .sbn index is up to date?

Comment: The shapefile is converted from .gdb by arcmap. I am not sure if the index is right.

Comment: Then try ogrinfo or ogr2ogr and see if everything is OK. If there are errors, delete .sbn if you have such and try again. If there are still errors the whole shapefile may be corrupted. If ogrinfo reads the shapefile OK then the trouble is probably in your code.

Comment: `ogr2ogr -spat 20.18664413 30.18546493 20.637988 30.6368097 t.shp input.shp` worked without any errors.

Comment: It means that shapefile is OK and GDAL, when correctly used, can apply spatial filters to it without troubles. What is left is your code but unfortunately I can't say anything about that.

Comment: I attach my full codes, I hope it can help someone find the problem..... :(